# How can I tell why Web-start terminates with no confirmation after security confirmation?

Tags: java-web-start

I have a shortcut to a java web-start jnlp on my desktop. When I double click it, WS downloads the jnlp, and I assume other out of date jar files, then notifies me with "Security Warning", because our app sometimes requires users to manipulate files and such. After I accept the risk, and click "Run", the security warning disappears and the program is never heard from again. What can I do to figure out the cause?

I have tried moving the launch to a .bat file and running it there with a pause at the end, but there is still no output as to why it terminates without indication.

```
call "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaws.exe" -verbose -wait "http://devweb.corp.generasolutions.com/magcore/MagCoreDev.jnlp"
pause
```

This jnlp works for other people, there must be something on my machine that is causing this reaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found something. When I run the java control panel, it was telling me that all 7 installed versions of java were enabled. I disabled all but the one I am using for webstart and now my WS program starts.